# Riley Riddle #1: The accent is fake

Tags: riddle

Start a box of jokes for a card geek,
End with a safe thing: the Brits do it sleek!
Inside's not quite the Queen's way to say where to go
Though, to be fair, who to ask you don't know.

Hint 1:

> None of the answers are completely unique to Britain , but knowledge of British life can help

Hint 2:

> Knowledge of TCGs, British household electronics, and how someone ESL might be represented in dialogue, are all helpful here :)

Hint 3:

> If you are a watcher of Tom Scott, then the clue for the suffix will make more sense. The infix is associated with how dialogue might be written for an unintelligent character, or one with a thick accent. As for the whole word, where might you find things that most people don't know about)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the suffix could be

> GROUND, thanks to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEfP1OKKz_Q) and @flashstorm's extremely patient hints in the comments.

The prefix is

> UN. From @flashstorm, in Magic: The Gathering, Un-sets are not-tournament-legal joke sets, and the cards are distributed in boxes, so the box is literally filled with jokes.

The infix is

> DER. From @flashstorm, authors use the word 'der when a character can't pronounce there, like "Go over 'der!".

Somewhere you'd go when you don't know something...

> is UNDERGROUND (ie. if you don't know where something like a show is).

Comment: Right video, wrong word. What is the "safe thing" in that video?

Comment: Is this the new safe thing? @flashstorm...now to find any weird words that go with this...?

Comment: That's a very reasonable interpretation of the riddle and my clues, but unfortunately I think you'll have a very hard time finding a word ending with that and matching the other clues. If you manage to find one, I'll accept it, but it's not the word I used.

Comment: Back to the drawing board for me, @flashstorm! _This still doesn't work_

Comment: There are a lot of safe things, and if it's not fuse or plug...there's not much else in the video...

Comment: Sometimes what you're looking for is right under your feet.

Comment: Getting there....slowly but surely....

Comment: May I recommend eliminating all distractions, going outside, laying down in the grass, and really immersing yourself in the riddle?

Comment: I thought I already had the suffix, though...? Or does this have to do with the entire word?

Comment: Oh, you edited the answer! You got it :). Lets talk about the references. For the prefix, in Magic: The Gathering, Un-sets are not-tournament-legal joke sets, and the cards are distributed in boxes, so the box is literally filled with jokes. For the infix, I'll admit this is the most BS clue I've tried. I have repeatedly seen authors use the word 'der when a character can't pronounce there, like "Go over 'der!". For the suffix, British plugs are well designed to ensure the ground is always active. As for the word, well, if you don't know where something like a show is, it's underground :).

Comment: Huh, I would've never got the infix, or the prefix for that matter. Good puzzle though! Now time to work on your latest one... :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> pungencies?

Start with a collection of jokes for a geek,

> A pun

End with a safe thing: the Brits do it sleek!

> The sea. Britain was known for it's navy. And the sea can be very calming, very safe.

Inside's not quite the Queen's way to say where to go

> A gent, as in a gentleman. The queen can't say where to go, because a gent is a man.

Though, to be fair, who to ask you don't know.

> Who smells bad? You can't ask, because it is rude.

Hence, you have

> pun-gent-sea or pungencies.

Comment: Clever, but not quite! The riddle does not rely on  
homophones